# How to implement a single queue with multiple consumers

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, queue

I have a list `list_of_params` and a function `run_train()` that receives an item from the `list_of_params` (e.g. `run_train(list_of_params[0])`). I can dispatch `run_train()` to multiple GPUs at a time. So i'd like if there is any implementation of a single queue that can be paralelized.

If this is not clear enough, imagine the following scenario:

"A supermarket which has a single customer queue, but 5 cashiers. Once a cashier is idle, it process the products of the next customer in the queue. This is the contrary of each cashier having its own line."

I can provide more details if needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) module. 'Thread-safe multi-producer, multi-consumer queues'.

Comment: I didn't understand the  'Thread-safe multi-producer, multi-consumer queues'. Is this a design pattern?

Comment: My bad, by  'Thread-safe multi-producer, multi-consumer queues' i meant that locking and synchronization is done for you, and exposed via simple API (basically first paragraph of docs). Use it with producer-consumer flow or however you want.
You can prepopulate queue with task data, then let threads pick tasks one by one. IDK what framework you're using, and how it dispatches tasks to GPUs, maybe it has some kind of queues inside, that you can use.
`glfh`

Comment: If you are using multiprocessing, then you need to use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20queue#multiprocessing.Queue).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a queue with a few producer and consumer processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event
#if you use threading instead of multiprocessing, use queue.Queue rather than multiprocessing.Queue
from queue import Empty
from time import sleep
from random import random

def producer(stopflag, out_queue):
    while True:
        if stopflag.is_set():
            break
        sleep(random()) #sleep anywhere from 0-1 sec avg 0.5 (producer will produce on average a maximum of 2 outputs / sec)
        out_queue.put(random()) #may wait if the queue is currently full, thereby reducing production rate.
        
def consumer(stopflag, in_queue):
    while True:
        if stopflag.is_set():
            break
        x = in_queue.get()
        sleep(x*2) #consumers work twice slower than producers averaging 1 item per sec

def main():
    stopflag = Event()
    
    shared_q = Queue(maxsize=100) # if the queue fills up, it will force the producers
                                  #   to wait for the consumers to catch up. Otherwise, it
                                  #   may grow infinitely (until the computer runs out of memory)
    
    #2 producers
    producers = [Process(target=producer, args=(stopflag, shared_q)) for _ in range(2)]
    #4 consumers
    consumers = [Process(target=consumer, args=(stopflag, shared_q)) for _ in range(4)]
    
    for process in producers + consumers:
        process.start()
        
    sleep(20) #let them work a while
    
    stopflag.set() #tell them to stop
    
    for process in producers + consumers: #wait for them to stop
        process.join()
        
    #empty unfinished tasks from the queue so its thread can exit normally
    #(it's good practice to clean up resources kind of like closing files when done with them)
    try:
        while True:
            shared_q.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        pass
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```